# SASS variables not working as expected in Vite project

Tags: sass, vite

As explained in [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html), I installed SASS into my Vite project by doing `npm add -D sass`.

Then as instructed in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSu2nq1tphU), in my `<head>` tag I have:

```
<head>
  <style lang="sass">
    @import url('src/assets/styles/main.scss');
  </style>
</head>
```

Nested styles work, but not variables:

If in my `main.scss` I have `$primary: #0fcbff;` and if I try to style an element using that variable like for instance `border: 3px solid $primary`, then `$primary` fails to get replaced by its value and in Chrome I actually see "border: 3px solid $primary" which of course is meaningless for Chrome.

Imports (like `@import "header";`) don't seem to work either.

If I comment stuff out I also get this error:

> [plugin:vite:css] [postcss] postcss-import:
> D:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\src\assets\styles\main.scss:13:8: Unknown
> word

Are these issues related and how to make it work?

(also I'm genuinely curious how something as elemental as CSS images can be an issue by default..!)

Comment: Hi! I'm currently struggling with the same thing as you described here. Have you been able to solve this problem?